# Two edges for same node and add circle to node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-qtree, qtree

I have three  issues with my qtree figure:

1. How can I add more than one edges for the same child?
2. How can I add a Circle to an edge?
3. I can't get a clue on how to organize the nodes like the image:

[image]

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree,tikz-qtree-compat}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel} % Manejo de idiomas}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style={draw,edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south)-- +(0,-8pt)-| (\tikzchildnode)}}}
\tikzset{
  every tree node/.style={
    rounded corners=1mm,
    draw,
    align=center,
    anchor=north,
    text width=8cm,
    font=\sffamily
    },
  level 1/.style={level distance=3cm},
  level distance=4cm,
  sibling distance=10pt,
}
\Tree [.\node (origen) {¿Se conoce la relacion confiabilidad/edad para esta falla?}; \edge node[fill=white,near end] {Si}; \edge node[fill=white,near end] {Parcial};
    [.\node{¿Es posible aplicar tareas TD?};  ]
]

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I apologize if my code looks simple but I don't have any idea on how to solve these issues

Comment: Since this isn't really a tree, you might be better off drawing it using regular nodes and connections rather than using `tikz-qtree`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that a tree adds unnecessary hassle to this. Here's a starting point for you. Feel free to comment for clarifications.

### Explanation

> `label=180:(1)`

This command adds a label to the node. The number `180` sets the angle where the label will appear. They work like this:

- `0` = right
- `90` = top
- `180` = left
- `270` = bottom

> `($(origen.south)+(0,-1.5)$)`

This one requires the tikz library `calc` and basically it calculates a point. In this case it starts from the south of the node named `origen` and adds `-1.5` on the Y axis, therefore going downwards.

> `origen.220`

This one uses the same logic as the first one, basically the line will start from the node named `origen` at 220 degrees, therefore below left.

> `(origen.220|-dos.north)`

This is done to calculate a perpendicular line. It will start from the coordinate in the previous point and it will stop when it reaches the same height as the north point of the node named `dos`. The `|-` basically means "first vertical, then horizontal".

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{
    every node/.style={
        %rounded corners=1mm,
        align=center,
        font=\sffamily
    },
    main/.style={
        draw,
        text width=5cm
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% Nodes
\node[main, label=180:(1)] (origen) {¿Se conoce la relacion confiabilidad/edad para esta falla?}; 
\node[main,anchor=east, label=180:(2)] (dos) at ($(origen.south)+(0,-1.5)$) {¿Es posible aplicar tareas TD?};
\node[main, label=180:(3)] (otro) at ($(origen.south)+(0,-4)$) {bla bla}; 

\node[main, text width=3cm, circle, anchor=west] (circ) at ($(origen.south east)+(0,-1.5)$) {bla bla bla bla bla};
% Edges
\draw (origen.220) -- (origen.220|-dos.north) node[midway, right] {Partial};
\draw (origen.195) -- (origen.195|-dos.north) node[midway, left] {Yes};
\draw (origen.340) -- (origen.340|-otro.north) node[pos=.2, right] {No};

\draw[dashed] (circ.west) -- (circ.west-|origen.340);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your answer works perfect but I can't understand it. Can you provide me some comments for commands like label=180:(1) or $(origen.south)+(0,-1.5)$ ?  because I'm gonna need to extend this work

Comment: @jd1215 What is it you don't understand? Or nothing at all? :D

Comment: @jd1215 Ah ok, sure.

Comment: If you scale my understanding from 0 to 100% I think in a 35% TBH lol

Comment: @jd1215 See edited answer. I added a couple of points.

Comment: @jd1215 You're welcome and no problem! If you have trouble with other parts of the graph, feel free to ask a new question (you can link this one in it for reference).